# How to remove multiple lines in a file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How to remove multiple lines in a file using Powershell? I am trying to delete some chunk of lines (line 16 to line 1463) from a file (notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gc -head + gc -tail should be good enough.
For convenience,

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$al = (gc yourfile)
$al.removeRange(15, 1463 - 16)
$al > yourfile
```